# Model column doesn't exist in __EFMigrationsHistory of EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am working with EF Core in Code-First approach. Everything is working well as like EF 6.0 for migration, creating tables, relationships, etc. But, one thing missing with __EFMigrationsHistory table, there should be a column 'Model' to store binary data of migration. Model column was not created when I run update-database command. Please check mine below codes and image.

[image]

**DbContext**

```
namespace ProfileCore.DataAccess
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents DB Context (DbSet, Configuration and common activities)
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ProfileCoreDbContext: DbContext, IDbContext
    {
        #region Ctor

        public ProfileCoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<ProfileCoreDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        #endregion

        #region Authentications DbSets
        public virtual DbSet<UserType> UserType { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Utilities

        /// <summary>
        /// Further configuration the model
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="modelBuilder">The builder being used to construct the model for this context</param>
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

**Update-Command:**

```
Update-Database -Migration 20190703213515_FirstMigration
```

Comment: *"Is model column deprecated in EF Core?"* Not sure why you care, but looks like it is. As usual for today's OS development, there is no much related documentation, you can get the default columns from the properties of the [HistoryRow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.historyrow?view=efcore-2.1) class.

Answer (score 0):

In EF Core the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table has only two columns, so what is shown in your screenshot is correct.

When you run `Update-Database` it is not necessary to include the timestamp prefix of your migration.  So if you added a migration named `FirstMigration` you may end up with a file `20190703213515_FirstMigration.cs`, but what you want to run is this

```
Update-Database -Migration FirstMigration
```

Comment: Thanks, Ray, I was expecting the Model column as like EF 6.0 to store each migration record in binary format, therefore I can rollback the migration.

Comment: No problem. Hope this helps :)